# update panel not working in where upload excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net

If i am using update panel then PostedFile not giving file path some error are coming and if update panel are removed the page then excel file successfully upload how to solve

Comment: Please show code to illustrate the problem, with proper error message and perhaps a screenshot. What you've written doesn't help understand the problem. See [ask] for more tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FileUpload inside UpdatePanel won't work. You have to post the whole page. You do this by adding a PostBackTrigger to the button you use for uploading files.

Something like this (see Triggers):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Width="400px" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUploadFiles" runat="server" Text="Upload files" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadFiles" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you have problems with not posting the first time a button is clicked then add this to Page Load event:

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

Answer (score 2):

your code should be as shown below

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="flFile" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You need to put postback trigger if you are uploading any files.